# Rails gem list for Code track and Query issue optimizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

is there not my issue but for my knowledge improvement i also known which gem are use in rails for **Track our rails app code** and **find issue in query**.

please, help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what exactly are you looking for, but:

**Rubocop**
https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop -- is a best gem for tracking code quality and syntax style.

**Bullet**
https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet -- verify your queries to find N+1 issues (https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/). But it's get fired only when you really trigger some action. At least I've never looked for or faced a way to run it through whole app.

Comment: Thanks @AntonTkachov it is useful for me.